# Why do only parts of my background color change in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I was following some tutorials in youtube, and I learned how to add background color using `android:background = "#006699"`. However, I realized only parts of my emulator screen gets colored when I use this code. It looks like this
[image]

Here is my code for content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background = "#006699"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="137dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Only up to where the text box is gets colored. Why does this happen? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your layout has `wrap_content` value set for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`. You should use `match_parent` value instead.

`wrap_content` makes layout to size itself according to its children size.

`match_parent` on the other hand makes it to fully extend to maximum available size of its parent. In this case, when it is root layout, to extend to the whole available space.

Comment: Oh I didn't know the meaning of those attributes yet. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Make height and width of `ConstraintLayout` to `match_parent` from `wrap_content`.

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modify like below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```